# Find the minimum value of a SQL table attribute and create a new table of attributes?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three SQL tables. The first is SCUBA_CLASSES with attributes CLASSID and CLASSNAME. Second is a table called STUDENTS with attributes STUDENTID and AGE. Third is a table TAKES_CLASS with attributes STUDENTID and COURSEID.

How do I create a new table that displays the CLASSID and CLASSNAME of the youngest student in the group?

I have:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUNGEST_STUDENT_ENROLLMENT
SELECT SCUBA_CLASSES.CLASSID AS CLASSID, SCUBA_CLASSES.CLASSNAME AS CLASSNAME
FROM SCUBA_CLASSES, STUDENTS, TAKES_CLASS
WHERE MIN(STUDENTS.AGE)
```

Not sure what to do from here. I have to find the youngest student and output the CLASSID and CLASSNAME of all the classes they are enrolled in.

Comment: is there any relationship between SCUBA_CLASSES and STUDENTS table?

Comment: No, there is no relationship between the two. The only relationship between them is the TAKES_CLASS table which contains the STUDENTID attribute (shared with STUDENTS) and the CLASSID attribute (shared with SCUBA_CLASSES).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem a `VIEW` would be a better fit than a table. The view will update automatically when new students are enrolled;

```
CREATE VIEW YOUNGEST_STUDENT_ENROLLMENT AS
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SC.CLASSID, SC.CLASSNAME, S.NAME, S.AGE, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SC.CLASSID ORDER BY AGE) RN
  FROM SCUBA_CLASSES SC
  JOIN TAKES_CLASS TC ON SC.CLASSID = TC.CLASSID
  JOIN STUDENTS S ON S.STUDENTID = TC.STUDENTID
)
SELECT CLASSID,CLASSNAME,NAME,AGE FROM cte WHERE RN=1;
```

This view will always contain the person with the lowest age per class. If you want it to contain only the lowest aged person no matter which class, you can remove the `PARTITION BY SC.CLASSID` clause.

[An SQLfidde to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/37df6/1).

Comment: Actually, all of the table attributes are VARCHAR(15), except for AGE, which is NUMBER. When I changed all of the values to VARCHAR, the code broke. Is there a way to do this when only AGE is an integer?

Comment: Yes, here are my changes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2a49b/1. I think only class 1 and class 4 should show up.

Comment: @JIL If you just want one student, remove the `PARTITION BY` as in  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08347/1

Comment: Shouldn't classID 1 and classID 4 both show up? The table should display all the classes taken by the youngest student (12 years old). So, I think that is class #1 and class #4.

Comment: @JIL Ah, I see what you mean, then you need to use `RANK() OVER` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0cc79/1

Comment: Ok, I just saw it :P Thanks!

Comment: @JIL I linked a fiddle where I mentioned `RANK`, basically it just replaces `ROW_NUMBER()` where you want ties to rank the same. `ROW_NUMBER` will just pick an arbitrary order for ties, which means just one row can rank lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this nested query:-

```
CREATE TABLE YOUNGEST_STUDENT_ENROLLMENT AS (
SELECT SCUBA_CLASSES.CLASSID AS CLASSID, SCUBA_CLASSES.CLASSNAME AS CLASSNAME
FROM SCUBA_CLASSES
WHERE SCUBA_CLASSES.CLASSID IN (SELECT  TAKES_CLASS.CLASSID FROM TAKES_CLASS
WHERE TAKES_CLASS.STUDENTID IN (SELECT  STUDENTS.STUDENTID FROM STUDENTS
WHERE STUDENTS.AGE IN (SELECT MIN(STUDENTS.AGE) as AGE FROM STUDENTS))));
```

Comment: I got an error message: WHERE SCUBA_CLASSES.CLASSID = (SELECT TAKES_CLASS.CLASSID FROM TAKES
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command

Comment: I can't seem to use whitespace here. There should be a newline break between "TAKES" and "ERROR".

Comment: I noticed there are 2 closing parentheses, but 3 opening ones, so I added a parentheses at the end of "STUDENTS.AGE)));" then ran in in oracle. It's giving a strange answer "SELECT * FROM YOUNGEST_STUDENT_ENROLLMENT  
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"